# No screen when using turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a square using turtle in python, however, it's not opening any screen.

There are no errors in the shell. I am using python 2.7.14 on windows 10

```
import turtle

def draw_square(some_turtle):
    for i in range(1,5):
        some_turtle.forward(100)
        some_turtle.right(90)


def draw_art ():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("green")

    fahim = turtle.Turtle()
    fahim.shape("turtle")
    fahim.color("yellow")
    fahim.speed(2)
    for i in range(1,37):
        draw_square(fahim)
        fahim.right(10)


    window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You have told Python how to draw a square. You have not told Python to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the functions, but you haven't called them.

Functions only run when they're called, and as you haven't called them, no animation will be displayed. This means that you need to call your functions o get the animation.

Just add `draw_Art()` to the end of your code and there should be an animation.